Does "import java.util.*" incur a performance loss?
Suppose I have a Java class with only one dependency in java.util: that is, java.util.Scanner. And instead of writing import java.util.Scanner I write (lazily) import java.util.*.
Is the compiler smart enough to only import java.util.Scanner? Or does it actually import every class from java.util?
What exactly are the performance gains of writing import java.util.Scanner in this case? That is, which of the following is true?

It makes the code compile faster.
It makes the code run more efficiently (e.g. uses less memory).
There are no performance gains.


Linked answer is a more thorough discussion than you requested, but your answer does lie within.

you must be aware that import is only importing the namespace - once the compiler found the class, the fully qualified name of the class is used in compiled code - there is no import in the class file, no difference in compiled code (just the compiler may be slightly slower since it must scan the whole package to find the class == eventually point 1 above, but more probably point 3)

“What exactly are the performance gains of writing import java.util.Scanner in this case?”  Zero.  Absolutely nothing.  Not even negligible;  it is literally a flat zero.  Importing is purely a compile-time convenience.  Java has no class named Scanner.  It does have a class named java.util.Scanner.  The import statement simply tells the compiler, “Wherever you see ‘Scanner’ in my code, assume it’s shorthand for java.util.Scanner.”

In addition to what VGR said, while import java.util.Scanner; says “Wherever you see ‘Scanner’ in the code (and it’s not a variable or local class), use ‘java.util.Scanner’”, the statement “import java.util.*;” says “Wherever you see an identifier in the code that can not resolved by other means, check whether there’s a matching type in the ‘java.util’ package” Assuming otherwise unchanged code, the ‘Scanner’ symbol is the only one falling into that category, so the only lookup ever happening will be for ‘java.util.Scanner’. In other words, not even the compile-time performance will change
